# I am making a launcher project with python tkinter, and i am having some issues

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, project

I am making a Game launcher software in python tkinter and as i am new to tkinter.

in the app, you can add the games in your pc using the browse option, and you can access all the games in the same launcher. and there is even an option for where you can upload the into the launcher by uploading the exe file and giving its details.

I am having some issues making this.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT and definitely don't ask anyone's email address.

Comment: what issues exactly are You having, please clarify what You want and provide a [mre]

Comment: hi, I would like to help You but You have to provide Your code, read hot to create a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

I just happened to have this code in my IDE from a person I previously helped:

```py
import os
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
import time

def browse():
    app_bro = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='',filetype = [('Application', '*.exe')])

    name = os.path.basename(app_bro)

    moment=time.strftime("%Y-%b-%d__%H_%M_%S",time.localtime())

    username = os.getenv("UserName")
    path = f"C:\\Users\\{username}\\Downloads\\{name}"

    os.system(f"start {path}")

    return {"app":app_bro, "name":name, "moment":moment, "username":username, "path":path}

browse()
```

Ur welcome :)